# button does not appear in design view android studio

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Building an android app. The idea is to open a second activity.
When building get an error class interface or enum expected where it says Activity { Button button ... and also where it says void
I have two Java files. MainActivity.java and Main2Activity.java. The problem appears to be with the first one. Code follow package

```
package com.cancunsteve.aboutcancunsteve;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Locate the button in activity_main.xml
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MyButton);

    // Capture button clicks
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Start NewActivity.class
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? give us more details

Comment: try extended your MainActivity with AppCompatActivity

Comment: that helps but still error class interface or enum expected where it says 'Activity { Button button'

Comment: I don't know if it is me but why do you have TWO onCreate methods? And why one is outside the class? Does this code even compile?

Answer (score 0):

if you say that the second activity is called MainActivity2 then the Intent should be like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    MainActivity2.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something very wrong with yoour code! This code will never compile!

First, you have two duplicate methods!

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

And this one inside the MainActivity class

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Locate the button in activity_main.xml
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MyButton);

    // Capture button clicks
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Start NewActivity.class
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    NewActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

Second, one of your method is declared outside the MainActivity class! I think this is where your issue comes from! Java thinks this line : `public class MainActivity extends Activity {...}` is an enum or a class! That's what the error says!

Delete the first onCreate method and your problem should be solved!

Comment: your advice worked. thanks. the issues now are 'cannot find symbok class Activity' 'method does not override from supertype' 'cannot find symbol setContentView' 'cannot find symbol intent'

Comment: You should accept this answer first then ask another question with the actual error!